# PyQt bug with QLIneEdit

Tags: python, pyqt

When QLineEdit() is used in text it appears to create a bug in lists and dictionaries,this code works:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
a=[1,2]
b=a[0]
print(b)
```

but when a line edit is added python will crash

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
c=QLineEdit()
a=[1,2]
b=a[0]
print(b)
```

I have found this when using the Anaconda package on multiple computers, can anyone suggest a work around which does not involve not using lists or dictionaries.

Comment: Do you get error message ? Always add full error message (traceback) in question.

Comment: Please read the guidance on providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You use it in wrong way. First you have to use `QApplication(sys.argv)` which initiates all needed modules and librares.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

c = QLineEdit()
a = [1,2]
b = a[0]
print(b)
```

So find some PyQt5 tutorial.

---

**EDIT:** problem is not list or dictionary but `QListEdit` (or any other Widget) without `QApplication`

You get the same problem in

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
QLineEdit()
```

or

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
QWidget()
```

Comment: This was just a demonstration as It was an issue I found in a program about 500 lines long and the line edit was not intended to do anything but it does cause the error with lists and dictionaries.

Comment: You get the same error without lists and dictionars too. Problem is not list or dictioarny but `QListEditor` without `QApplication`.

Comment: The error was occurring in a full program with QApplication and no in console error message but as I would prefer not to post the program due to plagiarism checks I understand it would be very difficult for you to help. I did not realise due to this that it was a separate issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe they put `QListEditor` in wrong place. If it is open source code then maybe you should send information to author.